# Desktop application needs to support all versions of SharePoint and SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, client-object-model, deployment, csom

I am connecting to the different SharePoint environments using the CSOM. Whats the best way to deploy the available DLLs to support all SharePoint environments? Do I need to dynamically instantiate objects based on the SharePoint version selected?

Comment: Can you post some samples / examples of the code in your desktop application? If the 2013 CSOM can't connect to 2010 environments then maybe you could create some common layer / abstraction over the CSOM calls that your app makes